# migrate scm-manager- svn repo to git repo's branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control, scmmanager

I'm using scm-manager;

In that i'm using SVN and git. I need to migrate a SVN repository to a git repository's branch.

Example :

SVN repository name: test-3.2

Git repository name : test-3.0

In this git-test-3.0, i need a branch as test-3.2. under that SVN repository test-3.2 was to be migrated with all its commit history.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
   $ git svn clone http://svn/repo/here/trunk
```

You have more details here : [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Comment: this will create a separate repo; i need this under a existing git repo  in the form of  new branch

Comment: You can do that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307142/merge-svn-repo-with-git-repo

Comment: @soundararajan.c you can also merge two separate git repo together while keeping all histories.